# iTunes download stopped on Mac unexpectedly

Tags: itunes, music

As you can see in the image below, the downloads are stopped. I have no trouble download music on my iPhone, but on my Mac, I have a hard time figuring out how to resume the download. Can anyone help me?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Look in the downloads sheet. At the far right is an empty circle and a little circular arrow.

Click the little circular arrow, that will resume a stopped download.

This works the same way in the Safari downloads sheet.

Comment: …or click the big button marked "Resume Downloads" at the bottom...

Comment: @Tetsujin "Resume Downloads" does not work. iTunes will attempt to download, but before long the downloads are stopped.

Comment: @Steve Chambers I tried, but in the next second the downloads are stopped.

Comment: Reboot everything; your modem/router, any wifi & ethernet hubs, then your Mac. Try again.

Comment: Yah if downloads fail again *immediately* there is some sort of network issue. Rebooting everything up the line (Mac, Modems, Routers, etc) like @Tetsujin said. That should fix the problem. Besides he has a Mac encyclopedia in his brain (well it *seems* like it) and is usually correct.